# How to call external video url inside javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, external

I just want to replace a local video with an (external) youtube video. My code looks like this, I am not sure what string I have to use, so the script shows the external youtube video.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#div_demo').videoBG({
        mp4:'assets/tunnel_animation.mp4',
        ogv:'assets/tunnel_animation.ogv',
        webm:'assets/tunnel_animation.webm',
        poster:'assets/tunnel_animation.jpg',
        scale:true,
        zIndex:0
    }); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

just give the url of video to video element as,

```
$('video').attr('src', url)
```

and if you are not using jQuery then set it like this

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.setAttribute("src", url);
```

Comment: Thanks Schnill, I tried it, but I think I am missing something...


$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('#div_demo').attr('http://www.youtube.com/embed/9oU7wzzvYrU', url);
})

I am hosting the site here and the video is suppose to show up in the header container – as background: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1913634/GREADYVIDEO/index.html